# Is there such thing as a critical value for the coefficient of friction?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

Is it possible for coefficient of friction to be so high that no matter what force is applied to an object, the object will never move?

For example, if I have an incline and a box on the incline that weighs $W $ and the incline is $\theta$ where $\theta < 90$. Can I find a $\mu$ such that no matter what force I apply to the box, I can never accelerate the box up the incline?

Comment: One can glue or weld it on or design microscopic hooks like velcro. Some creatures have evolved to be able to scale even vertical surfaces... does that qualify as "friction" in your books?

Comment: The specific question in the book was using a horizontal force to push the block up the incline.  Is there a coefficient of friction such that no horizontal force can exceed?

Comment: The problem is that friction is a very complicated phenomenon on the microscopic level and you can always conjure up a "friction" process that is basically as strong as the materials themselves. "Ordinary friction" doesn't do that, but there is no good definition of what "ordinary friction" is and at what coefficient of friction it ends. At least I am not aware of a rational definition that would stand up to skepticism. So while for all practical purposes the answer is "no", the extremes are just not something that one can exclude with a simple definition.

Comment: as an example of such extreme behaviour in a vacuum see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_welding  most importantly, note the overlap with related friction-esque processes like galling, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> The specific question in the book was using a **horizontal** force to push
>   the block up the incline. Is there a coefficient of friction such that
>   no horizontal force can exceed?

I've emphasized the word horizontal, because it is not mentioned in the question (only in a comment) and it fundamentally changes the meaning of the question.

When the force applied to the block is horizontal, its component along the incline pushes the block up the incline, while its component normal to the incline increases the normal reaction and, therefore, the friction force.

Neglecting the mass of the block and assuming that this is not a homework question, if $\mu N = \mu F\sin (\theta)$ is greater than $F\cos (\theta)$ or if $\mu > cot(\theta)$, no matter how great the applied horizontal force is, it won't be able to move the block up the incline.

Comment: This should be the answer. It just shows one more time how important is to have the actual statment of the problem rather than an incomplet summary.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have specially prepared surfaces where the frictional forces are  working in a macroscopic manner and producing hurdles then it will be difficult to get over it - moreover for especially polished surfaces like glass surfaces the relative motion becomes very difficult as forces of adhesion comes into play.

for normal surfaces in contact:

regarding  pushing up a box on an incline  you need a force which can overcome the component of weight, $W \sin(\theta)$,  acting downward along the incline added to the frictional force $\mu W \cos (\theta)$ opposing the motion therefore a force $F$ acting along the incline to push up which can overcome  the above two forces together can allow you to accelerate the box up the incline.
the coefficient of static  friction on an incline is related to the angle of incline -its $\tan(\theta)$ ; so if your angle is such that its value is very large it will be rather impossible to push the box up.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically there is not limit to the coefficient of friction. So you just need to find the value of $\mu$ that does not result in any acceleration; moreover, you need to make the force applied $$F = W sin( \theta)$$ added to the force of friction.